# When to start MongoDB sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding, database

At the moment we run a MongoDB Replicaset containing 2 Servers + 1 Arbiter.

And we store about 150 GB of data in the databases on the replicaset.

Right now we are thinking about when to start with sharding. Because we are wondering if there is a point where you can't start sharding anymore.

It is obvious that we would have to start sharding before we run out of hard disk space, our cpu is overloaded or the overall performance goes down because of too little RAM.

Somebody also told me that there is a limit of 256 GB data size after which you can't start sharding anymore. Also I read the official documentation http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/ and "MongoDB the definitive guide", I could not proove that.

From your experience is there a limit where you should have started with sharding ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would start sharding when you hit about 60-70% resource utilisation. This could be both hard disk space and RAM. The 256 GB limit is indeed there, it's documented at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Sharding%20Existing%20Collection%20Data%20Size

Comment: Wasn't that fixed since it was more of a "bug"? I remember reading about it being fixed `:/`

Comment: that would be intersting ;) , and if i got the manual right once the collection is shared, it can exceed the 256 GB per shard right ?

Comment: @Dukeatcoding Yeah no limit on the size of a sharded collection (per shard as well) it is just pre-sharded, MongoDB has some problem going over 256GB when creating the shard, can't remember exactly what

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with "balacing" so transfering data to new shards. Still you could be right that this was a kind of bug a while ago.

Comment: @Dukeatcoding It could be to do with chunks being initially balanced, but either way the problem is still there :)

Comment: October 2015. Is this 256 GB limit still an issue?

Answer (score 9):

I have found the limit to be based on reads/writes; afterall sharding is about increasing capacity, mainly writes, while replica sets being more concerned with reads. However, using separate servers (nodes) for ranges of data (shard key) can help reads too so it does have a knock on effect for both.

For example you could be only using 40% of your current servers memory with your current working set but due to the amount of writes being sent to that single server you could actually be seeing speed problems due to IO. At this time you would take sharding into account.

So really I would personally say, and this question is heavily opinion based, that you should shard when you feel as though you need more capacity for operations than is cost effective for a single replica set.

I have known of single replica setups that can take what, normally, an entire cluster would but it depends on how big your budget is. As a computer gets bigger it gets more expensive.

Comment: you maybe right with the performance. Since we have some hundred writes per seconds the locking time gets higher and higher, this should also improve by sharding shouldn't it ?

Comment: @Dukeatcoding 100 wties a sec is creating locking problems? Hmmm my nodes can handle upto 1 million operations a second...each

Comment: @Dukeatcoding You might have an optimisation problem here, it is normally recommended to seek optimising your database before you decide to shard it

Comment: you might be right we are using kind of an anti-pattern right now using one collection as queue with status flags for different operations ;) Before mongo we used a mysql for that which got totaly overloaded.
What kind of hardware do you have that you can handle a million write operations ? Our main server is only a i7 Quad - 48 GB RAM

Comment: @Dukeatcoding I have, for some nodes, an ssd backed instance with about 20gb RAM and a diddy little i7 quad, the ssd helps me to shove that working set into RAM, but some of my AWS instances don't have HIOPs or SSDs and I think I get close to about 800K ops out of them.

Comment: Sounds cool ;) Since we want fully control of our data, we won't go to AWS i think, but maybe we try the SSDs some day

Comment: @Dukeatcoding If you want to trial ssds you can try: http://objectrocket.com/ just as a trial, but yeah, hope it works out :)